# Suggestion for Automatically Match Data in MysQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, jupyter-notebook

I have limited access to the MySQL database, I just can see a view called customer contains customer_id, name, and their location

```
id_customer  name   location
1            Andy   Detro.it
2            Ben    CALiforNIA
3            Mark   uk
4            Niels  London123
5            Pierre Paris
```

And a table called location contain list of city and country of customer location.

```
id_coutry  country  id_city  city
1          US       1        Detroit
1          US       2        California
2          UK       3        London
2          UK       4        Manchester
```

I want to clean customer data automatically if there is new data in the database, I mean if in the raw data there is punctuation or number or typo, it will automatically clean and then after that the clean location will search their id_city based on location table, if there is no city similar/match, it will search id_country, and if there is no the id_city/country will be 0. and it will become new table called customer location

```
id_customer   id_city  status
1             1        Match
2             2        Match
3             2        Country
4             3        Match
5             0        Unknown
```

The status is label if the location is from city then it will be Match, if it's from country it will be Country, if there is no similar name or id_city/country 0 it will be unknown. The location can be city or country so the status will tell it's match with the city or with the country.

Can someone suggest what I must to do this project, I try to do it with python in jupyter notebook but will it be effective for this case? I really new to this things, sorry if I can't give enough information and thanks before.

Comment: use triggers events on Insert  
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115632/create-trigger-mysql-update-or-insert-in-another-table

Comment: I have read thsia number of times and still don't get it. You could help clarify by labelling the first 2 tables and explaining what the status column means in the customer_location table. As far as cleansing is concerned you will have to write code for every possible error in the customer profile table. Also please confirm that the location can be country or city or just plain garbage,,

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @P.Salmon I try to explain it more detail, hope it can be clearer

Comment: Let's see the complete list of typos you want to catch.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just add another column to you customer table, e.g. location type, rather than create a new table(better still, put id_country and id_city on your customer table). You would normally create a customer location table separately if a customer could have many locations, but in your data structure, they can't. If you want them to be able to have many locations then you need to rework your customer table too.

Comment: **Why would you** create work for yourself in this manner by RETROATIVELY and  REACTIVELY sanitizing database content? User input checks combined with enforced DB field types and prepared SQL ststements will remove 99% of this work for you **before** it even begins to exist...

Answer (score 2):

This is a very stacked question with lots of steps needed to achieve what you want. So let's dive straight in!

First, we should read the data frames from your (uncleaned) customer database and your location database:

```
import pandas as pd

customer_df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM customer", db_connection)
location_df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM location", db_connection)
```

Now that we have the data stored in proper frames to handle them, we can start to clean the locations in your customer database. There are MANY ways to do so! Your requirements were as follows:

> there is punctuation or number or typo

Now let's tackle the first two issues. We can do this using [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for cleaning out punctuations or numbers: `pattern = r"[^a-zA-Z\s]"`! With that pattern at hand we first clean the customer location data:

```
pattern = r"[^a-zA-Z\s]"
customer_df["location"] = customer_df["location"].str.replace(pattern, "")
```

For your typo issues there is no one-solution-fits-all. You could use a dictionary for often mismatches. Or review the database and add important ones manually. There are also a few libraries which can calculate the "distance" between the intended and actual word.

A good library *(subjective opinion - though no affiliation)* is [FuzzyWuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) as it allows you to use different metrics, such as the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or the [Jaccard similarity index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)!

```
import fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import process

levenshtein_matches = process.extract(
    customer_df["location"], location_df["city"], limit=1, scorer=fuzzywuzzy.fuzz.token_set_ratio
)
```

*Note that this is just an example. You may go ahead and read the docs or a good article I found on [Medium](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/fuzzy-matching-in-python-2def168dee4a)!*

You do need to do this twice for both the `location_df["city"]` and location_df["country"]`. Use an algorithm of your choice (depending on the average data you're getting) - but as mentioned, with the data you included I cannot conclusively decide for you what's best to use.

Now you can use a threshold value to determine whether a city / country is similar enough to be considered! A radical example: But if you got lots of customers from Iran or Iraq, you may need to adjust the values accordingly ;)

```
customer_df.loc[
    levenshtein_matches["ratio"] > threshold, "id_city"
] = levenshtein_matches["match"]
```

*Again, please do this for both the country and city!*

Now, lastly, let's bring together the hard work we've done! I now create a new table  with three columns: `id_customer` (which are the ids from the first table), `id_city` (which is either the city ID or country ID depending on the status) and a `status` (which will display `Match` = exact city was found, `Country` = only the country could be matched and `Unknown` = no data found -> in that case the default ID will be 0)!

**Create the final dataframe**:  `customer_location_df = customer_df[["id_customer"]].copy()`

Now **set the id_city** as described *(as mentioned above - you need to do this for country on your own, I sampled the code for city for you)*:

```
customer_location_df.loc[
    (customer_df["id_city"].notnull()) & (customer_df["ratio"] > threshold), "id_city"
] = customer_df["id_city"]
customer_location_df.loc[
    (customer_df["id_city"].isnull()) & (customer_df["id_country"].notnull()) & (customer_df["ratio"] > threshold), "id_city"
] = customer_df["id_country"]
customer_location_df.loc[
    (customer_df["id_city"].isnull()) & (customer_df["id_country"].isnull()), "id_city"
] = 0
```

Create the **`status` column** and set it:

```
customer_location_df.loc[
    (customer_df["id_city"].notnull()) & (customer_df["ratio"] > threshold), "status"
] = "Match"
customer_location_df.loc[
    (customer_df["id_city"].isnull()) & (customer_df["id_country"].notnull()) & (customer_df["ratio"] > threshold), "status"
] = "Country"
customer_location_df.loc[
    (customer_df["id_city"].isnull()) & (customer_df["id_country"].isnull()), "status"
] = "Unknown"
```

Lastly, save the `customer_location_df` as a **new table in the database**: `customer_location_df.to_sql("customer_location", db_connection, if_exists="replace")` *(careful not to replace your main table if it's called `customer_location`)*!

Comment: Please note that this is not the full code. I outlined the basic process and how to do the most important parts (i.e. using RegEx to get rid of the basic "dirt", then use a library such as FuzzyWuzzy to detect simple mistakes and then how to clean the basic table)! :)
Please let me know if I should go in-depth with a step in the process.

Comment: levenshtein is quite costly (must check every item); and not very useful.

Comment: @RickJames It’s a suggestion. The RegEx itself solves all of his cases! I just included a way for him to correct spellings (which library and algorithm he ends up using doesn’t matter as it wasn’t the focus of the question)!

Comment: Does it handle transpositions and single-letter misspellings?

Comment: Can adapt it if you use the proper `fuzzywuzzy` implementation. OP didn't provide most any reproducible code - developing the whole solution wasn't possible and thus I provided an outline (step by step how to approach the issue) and included example code for each step! ;)

Comment: And the current implementation is able to catch single-letter misspellings and transpositions (if the treshhold is set accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly here..

***[...] I mean if in the raw data there is punctuation or number or typo, it will automatically clean [...]***

You need some sort of validation method here, you cannot achieve that directly on the database, you need to handle it in your logic before the rows insertion.

In these cases, the best solution is to prepare a picklist (multiple choice) from which end users can choose the right values.

A free text input will always be error prone.

If the multiple choiceis not an applicable solution in your case, then you need to put in place a list of validation rules but you need to think how to prevent every possible issue.

Example, in your case:

You could use Regex to clean the input

```
import re

city = 'Detro.it'
cleanCity= re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', city)

print(cleanCity) // Detroit
```

You need to play with regex in those manner, for exampe If you want extract only chars `[a-zA-Z]+`

In order to handle the input in a case sensitive way you could use `str.title()`
After that all the chars, except the firts one, are coverted to lowercase

```
city = "caliFORnia"
cleanCity = city.title()

print(cleanCity) // California
```

The final resulting table is obtainable via MySql query.
You need to JOIN the tables. (here the only common fiels is the name of the city, not the best for the ON cluase, an id would be better)

In order to achieve the derived column 'Staus' you could leverage the MySql function CASE.
Example:

```
 SELECT field1,field2,..,
 CASE
     WHEN field1 = field2 THEN "Match"
     ELSE "Unmatch"
 END AS Derived_Col
 FROM table;

 Result:

 field1   field2   Derived_col
 sometxt  sometxt  Match
 another  other    Unmatch
```